# pandas replace inner workings

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe train with the following content in line 24549

```
train.iloc[24549,:]
>>> 
id                                                           79571
product_uid                                                 123177
product_title    Charlotte Pipe 3/4 in. PVC Sch. 40 90-Degree S...
search_term                                  3/4 in pvc assesories
relevance                                                     2.67
Name: 24549, dtype: object
```

I want to to replace 'assesories' with 'accessories' in train.iloc[24549,3]

If I do:

```
train = train.replace('assessories','accessories')
```

Whenever I check the df value after this command, the word in the above dataframe element is still 'assessories'.

However, if I do:

```
c =  train.iloc[24549,3]

c = c.replace('assessories','accessories')

c
>>>>  '3/4 in pvc accessories'
```

I am still scratching my head over this. I do not want to iterate through the df but rather do a vectorized implementation. Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right command is not

```
train = train.replace('assessories','accessories')
```

but

```
train = train.str.replace('assessories','accessories')
```

Thanks to my friend Lucas Eustaquio for pointing this out.